# Woocommerce login to specific page or referrer

Tags: redirect, woocommerce-offtopic, login

I setup a modified Woocommerce login form, to work with the membership plugin that I am using (Paid Membership Pro) with the help of this blog: [Redirect after logging in.](https://nicola.blog/2016/03/30/redirect-after-logging-in-based-on-the-user-role/)

```
   function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    // Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
global $current_user;

    $level = pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($user->ID);
    $myaccount = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );

if          ( $level->id == 2 ) {
            $redirect = '/rookie-dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 3 ) {
            $redirect = '/player-dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 4 ) {
            $redirect = '/all-star-dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 5 ) {
            $redirect = '/coach-dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 6 ) {
            $redirect = '/owner-dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 7 ) {
            $redirect = 'https://corporate.example.com/dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 8 ) {
            $redirect = '/dashboard/';

} else {
    $redirect = $myaccount;
}
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

However, I was wondering if it's possible to add a referrer to this function. Basically I want the function to first check to see if a specific page was requested, if so then they will be redirected to /member-login/ because the site is locked down, once logged in it would go to the specific page they originally requested. If the user didn't request a specific page then they would be redirected to the appropriate dashboard like I had above.

This was in the original code:

```
$redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
```

However, I'm not sure how to apply it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was actually pretty simple.

First I needed to modify my custom member login redirect to include the redirect_to portion in the redirect URL:

```
function pb4r_redirect()
{
    global $current_user;
    $refer=urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    $okay_pages = array(4, 10, 12, 13, 191, 200, 1380, 1381, 1382, 1383, 1449, 1631, 1643, 1652, 1653, 1654, 1666, 1718, 1725, 1840, 'Checkout', 'Cart', pmpro_getOption('billing_page_id'), pmpro_getOption('account_page_id'), pmpro_getOption('levels_page_id'), pmpro_getOption('checkout_page_id'), pmpro_getOption('confirmation_page_id'));

   //if the user is logged out

 if(!$current_user->ID
     && !is_home()
     && !is_page($okay_pages)
     && !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "login")
     && !is_singular( 'post' )
     && !is_product()
    )
    {
        wp_redirect( '/member-login' . '?redirect_to=' . $refer );
        exit;
    } 
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'pb4r_redirect');
```

Then I modified the woocommerce function to include the redirect_to:

```
function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    // Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
global $current_user;

    $level = pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($user->ID);
    $myaccount = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );

if( isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
        return $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
}elseif      ( $level->id == 2 ) {
            $redirect = '/rookie-dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 3 ) {
            $redirect = '/player-dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 4 ) {
            $redirect = '/all-star-dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 5 ) {
            $redirect = '/coach-dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 6 ) {
            $redirect = '/owner-dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 7 ) {
            $redirect = 'https://corporate.example.com/dashboard/';
} elseif    ( $level->id == 8 ) {
            $redirect = '/dashboard/';

} else {
    $redirect = $myaccount;
}
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Now I am able to redirect users to the requested page. If they didn't request a page then they are automatically redirected to their dashboard. If they are a registered user but aren't part of a membership program then they are redirected to the My Account page.